# Type assertion and interfaces

Tags: go, interface

Why first example fails, but second goes well?

What is correct way to do such assertion?

example 1
https://play.golang.org/p/4LRGQLdGPB

```
// example 1
type Packet map[string]interface{}

func get(pack interface{}) {
    if packet, ok := pack.(Packet); !ok {
        fmt.Printf("error: %#v, %#v\n", pack, packet)
    }
}

func main() {
    pack := make(map[string]interface{})
    pack["qwe"] = 123
    get(pack)
}

// error: map[string]interface {}{"qwe":123}, main.Packet(nil)
```

example 2
https://play.golang.org/p/Pd9jvvNrq5

```
// example 2
type Packet map[string]interface{}

func get(pack interface{}) {
    var p Packet
    if packet, ok := pack.(map[string]interface{}); !ok {
        fmt.Printf("%#v, %#v\n", pack, packet)
    } else {
        p = packet
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p)
}

func main() {
    pack := make(map[string]interface{})
    pack["qwe"] = 123
    get(pack)
}

// main.Packet{"qwe":123}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not passing a `Packet`, you're passing a `map[string]interface{}`, which is a completely different type as far as Go is concerned.

If you use `pack := make(Packet)` or `pack := Packet{}`, it will work as intended.

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/oP3o3--6t2)

Comment: Can also be done by replace get(pack) to get(Packet(pack))

Answer (score 0):

The answers and comments so far are misunderstanding, mixing up, or at least brushing over a lot of detail in the difference between a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

The syntax `thing.(AType)` is a type assertion. It will be **evaluated at runtime**. The criteria for when this will be successful (i.e. `ok == true`) can be boiled down to really 2 situations:

1. `thing` is literally of type `AType`. Not a redeclared type like your `Packet`.
2. `AType` is an interface and `thing` satisfies the interface.

In all other cases, `ok` will be `false` (or if you use the single value version `foo := bar.(Baz)`, `foo` will be whatever the appropriate zero value is).

The syntax `AType(thing)` is a type conversion. It will be **evaluated at compile time**. A type conversion requires the in memory structure of `AType` and whatever type `thing` is, to be identical.

Therefore, in your example the type assertion, `packet, ok := pack.(Packet)` results in `ok == false` because `Packet` is a non-interface type, and `packet` is not literally of that type, it is of type `map[string]interface`.

However, you can do the type conversion `Packet(pack)`, because the type `Packet` and the variable `pack` have the same underlying memory structure, `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: **1. AType is an interface and thing satisfies the interface.** : if i have `var p interface{} = int(123)` then i can write `p.(int)` so, the rule is **thing is an interface, holding type AType**, isn't it ?

Comment: "if i have var p interface{} = int(123) then i can write p.(int) so, the rule is thing is an interface, holding type AType" is a specific case of my 1. In this example, while `p` has been declared as `interface{}`, the underlying data is literally of type `int`. However if you had defined `type Foo int`, you would find `p.(Foo)` fails because the underlying data of `p` is not of type `Foo`.

Comment: It may help to think of interface types as tuples, they reference 2 pieces of information: the type of the underlying struct, and the struct data itself.